# How to view files(docx, ppt, xlsx, etc.) from my project’s assets in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Im working on a flutter app that needs to view document files. Is there a way to open or view document files from my assets?

`FlutterPdfViewer.loadAsset(filepath)` works fine but `OpenFile.open(filepath)` only works with files within the phone’s storage. 
I can’t find any packages to view other file types besides pdf files from my project’s assets. Are there other ways? I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and didn't find a solution, so I think, that open_file plugin calls a native app to open a file. That's why you can't open a file from assets using other application.
I think that you have to save that file in storage, after that call open_file OpenFile.open() method.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought of saving the files in the storage but I can’t find a way to move/download files from my project’s assets to the storage via flutter. Or to download files from mysql to the phone’s storage.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on SO of reading an asset and writing it to a file in the application specific storage.